# How to create Immutable List in java?

Tags: java, collections, immutability

I need to convert mutable list object to immutable list. What is the possible way in java?

```
public void action() {
    List<MutableClass> mutableList = Arrays.asList(new MutableClass("san", "UK", 21), new MutableClass("peter", "US", 34));
    List<MutableClass> immutableList = immutateList(mutableList);
}

public List<MutableClass> immutateList(List<MutableClass> mutableList){
    //some code here to make this beanList immutable
    //ie. objects and size of beanList should not be change.
    //ie. we cant add new object here.
    //ie. we cant remove or change existing one.
}
```

#### `MutableClass`

```
final class MutableClass {
    final String name;    
    final String address;
    final int age;
    MutableClass(String name, String address, int age) {
        this.name = name;
        this.address = address;
        this.age = age;
    }
}
```

Comment: What you have there is not immutable, because you can very easily call the .add(Object o) method. Make a subclass of ArrayList, override the .add(..) method(s) and have it either have an empty implementation, or throw an unchecked exception.
And, make that class final, so you can't subclass it and change the implementation

Comment: You could Wrap list in another object and only implement the Iterable interface

Comment: Answer to your question : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750791/what-is-the-sense-of-final-arraylist

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians, you should look at the entire answer of this link, giving you the answer 3 lines under

Comment: yup.but if any body dont know about unmodifiableList() this was immpossible to get that, this is fix of my problem,since in this question user was asking for final.thanks.

Comment: I am sure that this question has been answered before, but it is not a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10750791/what-is-the-sense-of-final-arraylist

Comment: @dubey-theHarcourtians, corrected the mistake in my answer.

Comment: @aioobe answer given by MadP is also same,i prefered his answer to motivate him since he have less repo than U.

Comment: That's not a very good practice. You should accept the *objectively best* answer for the benefit of future readers.

Comment: exactly his answer is more descriptive as well.

Comment: Since you brought my attention to this question again, I realized there's a slightly better way to do it. Updated my answer.

Answer (score 76, accepted):

Once your `beanList` has been initialized, you can do

```
beanList = Collections.unmodifiableList(beanList);
```

to make it unmodifiable. (See [Immutable vs Unmodifiable collection](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8892350/276052))

If you have both internal methods that should be able to modify the list, and public methods that should not allow modification, I'd suggest you do

```
// public facing method where clients should not be able to modify list    
public List<Bean> getImmutableList(int size) {
    return Collections.unmodifiableList(getMutableList(size));
}

// private internal method (to be used from main in your case)
private List<Bean> getMutableList(int size) {
    List<Bean> beanList = new ArrayList<Bean>();
    int i = 0;

    while(i < size) {
        Bean bean = new Bean("name" + i, "address" + i, i + 18);
        beanList.add(bean);
        i++;
    }
    return beanList;
}
```

(Your `Bean` objects already seem immutable.)

---

As a side-note: If you happen to be using Java 8+, your `getMutableList` can be expressed as follows:

```
return IntStream.range(0,  size)
                .mapToObj(i -> new Bean("name" + i, "address" + i, i + 18))
                .collect(Collectors.toCollection(ArrayList::new));
```

Answer (score 22):

In JDK 8:

```
List<String> stringList = Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c");
stringList = Collections.unmodifiableList(stringList);
```

In JDK 9:

```
List stringList = List.of("a", "b", "c");
```

[reference](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/core/creating-immutable-lists-sets-and-maps.htm#JSCOR-GUID-DB0865D2-C052-40BC-A3DC-20FCB3088DC9)

Answer (score 13):

From Java 10 on, **`List.copyOf(Collection)`** can be used to return an unmodifiable list from the given collection. From source code of `List.copyOf` method:

- if the given collection is an unmodifiable List, `List.copyOf()` will not create a copy.
- if the given collection is mutable and modified, the returned list will not reflect such modifications. Meaning they are independent.

Comment: What do you mean by your second point?  By using `List.copyOf(Collection)`, are you making a defensive copy, similar to what https://stackoverflow.com/a/47461151/107158 suggests?

Comment: Indeed. See https://docs.oracle.com/javase/10/docs/api/java/util/List.html#copyOf(java.util.Collection) for more info.

Answer (score 12):

Use [`Collections.unmodifiableList()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/util/Collections.html#unmodifiableList(java.util.List)). You pass in your original `ArrayList` and it returns a list that throws an exception if you try to add, remove or shift elements. For example, use `return Collections.unmodifiableList(beanList);` instead of `return beanList;` at the end of `getImmutableList()`. `main()` will throw an exception. The `Collections` class has methods for all of the other common collection types besides `List` as well.

Answer (score 6):

**Creating empty immutable list before java SE 9**

Prior to Java 9, we have to use unmodifiableList() method of Collections class to create immutable list.

```
List<String> noElementList = new ArrayList<String>();
List<String> immuList = Collections.unmodifiableList(noElementList);
```

**Creating Non-empty immutable list before Java SE 9**

```
List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();
list.add("Atto");
list.add("Rick");
list.add("Shalini");
List<String> immuList = Collections.unmodifiableList(list);
```

**Java 9 – Creating Immutable list using static factory method of()**

```
List<String> immuList = List.of();
```

**Java 9 – Creating Non-empty immutable list**

```
List<String> immuList = List.of("Atto", "Rick", "Shalini");
```

Answer (score 4):

If are open to using a third party library, [Eclipse Collection](https://github.com/eclipse/eclipse-collections)s lets you convert from `MutableList` to `ImmutableList` and back again.

```
MutableList<String> mutable = Lists.mutable.with("a", "b", "c");
ImmutableList<String> immutable = mutable.toImmutable();
MutableList<String> mutableAgain = immutable.toList();
```

This also works with primitive collections.

```
MutableCharList mutable = CharLists.mutable.with('a', 'b', 'c');
ImmutableCharList immutable = mutable.toImmutable();
MutableCharList mutableAgain = immutable.toList();
```

If you have an `ArrayList` as the mutable `List`, the following will work.

```
List<String> mutable = new ArrayList<>(Arrays.asList("a", "b", "c"));
ImmutableList<String> immutable = Lists.immutable.withAll(mutable);
List<String> mutableAgain = immutable.toList();
```

Note: I am a committer for Eclipse Collections.

Answer (score 3):

Make it immutable instead of using directly unmodifiableList on list as otherwise still original list can be changed.

Basically unModifiable Collection is a view, So indirectly it could still be 'modified' from some other reference that is modifiable. Also as its just a readonly view of annother collection , When the source collection changes unModifiable Collection will always present with latest values.

However immutable Collection can be treated as a readonly copy of another collection and can not be modified. In this case when the source collection changes , immutable Collection do not reflect the changes

```
List<String> immutableList=Collections.unmodifiableList(
                            new ArrayList<String>(modifiableList));
```

Using guava:

```
import java.util.*; 
import com.google.common.collect.ImmutableList; 
ImmutableList<String> iList = ImmutableList.copyOf(list);
```

Answer (score 2):

Below solution is for making list as Immutable without using any API.

Immutable Object with ArrayList member variable

```
public final class Demo {

    private final List<String> list = new ArrayList<String>();

    public Demo() {
        list.add("A");
        list.add("B");
    }

    public List<String> getImmutableList() {
        List<String> finalList = new ArrayList<String>();
        list.forEach(s -> finalList.add(s));
        return finalList;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Demo obj = new Demo();
        System.out.println(obj.getImmutableList());
        obj.getImmutableList().add("C");
        System.out.println(obj.getImmutableList());
    }
}
```

So the actual list will not change, always output will be [A,B]

Comment: So `getImmutableList()` essentially creates a defensive copy of the list so that the client cannot modify the original list?

Comment: Yes, Client can not modify list