# Kotlin: Public getter returns immutable list but private getter should return mutable list

Tags: java, kotlin, collections

I want my class to have a field that is return an immutable list for all public accesses but inside the object instance I want the list to be mutable so I can add elements to it.

```kotlin
   class GrammarParser {
    private val grammars: List<Grammar> = mutableListOf()
    get() = field.toList()
   }
```

### Try

```kotlin
 class GrammarParser {
    private val _grammars: MutableList<Grammar> = mutableListOf()
    val grammars: List<Grammar>
    get() = this._grammars.toList()
   }
```

I tried this but am unsure if this is considered good practice?

Comment: Question already answered in following link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30348292/how-to-create-immutable-list-in-java . Unless you need it in Kotlin syntax?

Comment: @bramdc Conversion would not work in the first example since `get() = field.toMutableList()` would show a compiler error since the return value of `grammars` is `List<Grammar>` and not `MutableList<Grammar>` already tried that. Kotlin Syntax should be the way btw.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

In Kotlin, every `MutableList<T>` is also a `List<T>`. So, you can create a `MutableList` in a private field, and declare an additional field of type `List` that points to the same object. Inside the class, you can use the mutable reference to modify the list, and expose the `List` to outside.

Example:

```kotlin
class GrammarParser {
    private val mutableGrammars = mutableListOf<Grammar>()
    val grammars: List<Grammar> = mutableGrammars
}
```

In your second example, you create a copy (snapshot) of the list every time you call the getter. This means, after you call the getter and got a list, even if the `_grammars` is modified somewhere else, the changes will not be reflected in the read-only list view you got the reference of. This might be something you want - then what you are doing is ok. But if that's not something you are looking for, then the example I gave above will avoid the copying.

Comment: It's an important distinction that the `List` is not immutable. It is a read-only view of a mutable list.

Comment: @Tenfour04 you are right, I edited the answer to make it clearer. Thanks.